# Script doesnt connect to JsonResult Controller

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a problem with connecting the script with the autocomplete function to my Json controller. The view is a formula, where the user can insert data, like dates with the datepicker function and general text to describe the issues. The whole formula is in this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

All Textboxes, DropDownLists and Editors are connected to the model like so:

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Overview)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Overview)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Overview)
    </div>
```

At the moment I try to insert the Textbox, where the autocomplete should happen like this:

```
 <b>Name: </b>
     @Html.TextBox("searchTerm", null, new { id = "txtSearch" })
```

The txtSearch is connected to my skript SearchUser.js:

```
$(function () {
    $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
        source: '@url.Action("New1", "Dialog")',
        minLength: 1
    });
});
```

when I use a source an array of strings, the autocomplete appears.

the JavaScript is registered on top of the view and jQueryUI is registered in _Layout.cshtml. I am using jquery 1.11.3 and jqueryui 1.11.4 .

In The Controller `New1` in the JsonResult you find this:

```
public JsonResult Dialog(string search)
{
    List<string> users = db
                            .Users
                            .Where(p => p.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()))
                            .Select(p => p.LastName)
                            .ToList();

    return Json(users, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

when i test the website and look for http://localhost:51299/New1/Dialog?search=m
i get the json file. The json file contains this: `["Mueller"]`

But when I go to my formula http://localhost:51299/New1/Create and insert "m" into the TextBox nothing happens.

So now my question: What can i do to make it work?

---

### Update (It's working!!!)

Aaaaah its working!!!. Thanks a lot! He couldnt use the source, so now I changed it to "/New1/Dialog".
I know it is not a good way to use the direct url instead of '@url.Action("Dialog", "New1")', but i think he couldnt differ between normal **'** and **"**.
If you have an Idea why i couldnt use @url.Action, i would be interested in it.

**View (Create.cshtml)**

```
@Html.TextBox("searchTerm", null, new { id = "searchTerm" })
```

**Skript (SearchUser.js)**

```
$(function () {
$("#searchTerm").autocomplete({
    source: "/New1/Dialog",
    minLength: 1
});
});
```

**controller (New1Controller.cs)**

```
public JsonResult Dialog(string term)
    {
        List<string> users = db
                            .Users
                            .Where(p => p.LastName.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower()))
                            .Select(x => x.LastName)
                            .ToList(); 

     return Json(users, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Have you used your browser's developer tools to see if the request is completed successfully? If you place a breakpoint inside of the `Dialog` action, does it get hit?

Comment: Yes, i already did that and it doesnt get hit.

Comment: `@url.Action("New1", "Dialog")` points to method `New1()` in `DialogController`. To hit `Dialog()` in `New1Controller` it needs to be `@url.Action("Dialog", "New1")`

Comment: Thanks, that was also a big mistake but it also doesnt solve the Problem.

Comment: Ah, I see. You can't use razor helpers inside of JavaScript files, so the `@Url.Action(...)` was never being processed.

Comment: I now see that you were using an external .js file. Razor code is not parsed in external files. One option is use `Html.TextBox("searchTerm", null, new { id = "searchTerm", data_url = "Url.Action("Dialog", "NewEscalation") })` and then in the script, `source: $(this).data('url'),`

Answer (score 1):

jQueryUI autocomplete is using the name `term` (not `search`) to craft a request. In other words, when you type "m", it's sending the following request:

> http://localhost:51299/New1/Dialog?term=m

You should be able to fix this by simply renaming the parameter:

```
public JsonResult Dialog(string term)
```

Comment: I changed it, but it was not the defect. I also changed now :      @Html.TextBox("searchTerm", null, new { id = "txtSearch" }) to @Html.TextBox("searchTerm", null, new { id = "searchTerm" }) and also changed in the script to $("#searchTerm").autocomplete({

Comment: @MimiMüller: If you look at the request in the developer tools of your browser, what do you see? Is there an error?

Comment: when i insert m into the Text box this appears: <div style="display: none;">No search results.</div>         at the moment i use google chrome Browser

Comment: @MimiMüller: Ok, in chrome's "network" tab, what do you see after typing the letter?

Comment: Ah, i can See the error http-fault 404.0 - not found. The Name of it is: @url.Action(%22Dialog%22,%20%22New1%22)?term=m.     Type is: xhr, Initiator is jquery-1.11.3.JS:9664